# SharePoint Online: video files in Quick Links web part don't work

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, video, quick-links

Using SPO, I create a Quick Links web part (on a Modern page), add a link, select Site, and pick a video (MP4) file from a Document Library on the site.

The link appears, I can choose a thumbnail, etc. However, clicking it does nothing at all except it sometimes scrolls the window to place that link at the top.

Oddly enough, at least in Firefox if I press F5 to reload, **then** the video loads. This is inexplicable to me.

If, instead of using the Site option when adding a link, I use From link and paste in the link from the Document Library's "Copy Link" function, everything works.

SharePoint bug? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below steps, it is working in chrome, Mozilla and IE.

**Show a selected YouTube video**

Using this connection we can display the selected video in the “Embed” web part. To do this follow the below steps:

Add the below two web parts as like above image web part:

1. List web part and choose the list “Test Video List”
2. Add an Embed webpart.

Step 1 :

Adding List Web Part with “Test Video List”:

[image: Show selected video in SharePoint online webpart]

Step 2:

Adding an Embed web part and select “Test Video List” from connect to source drop down list as like below:

[image: Show selected video in SharePoint online webpart]

Note:

Fill the above embed code box with the below content where $VideoID is a variable that represents VideoID column in “Test Video List”.

“https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[$VideoID]”

Step 3:

Then we’ll see the below screen.

[image: Show selected video in SharePoint online webpart]

Step 4:

To verify the connection select any video from  the “List” web part that will be displayed in the “Embed” web part as like below.

[image: Show selected video in SharePoint online webpart]

For more details, please refer the below article:

[SharePoint Online: Connect web parts in SharePoint Online – O365](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/connected-web-parts-in-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: None of this has anything to do with my question, which was specifically about the Quick Links web part and video in a Document Library.

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach using MS stream. You can [upload the video to stream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/stream/portal-upload-video) and use the link to video or embed the video to your modern page.

I tested with it and it seems Chrome still has some issue with it. Edge works perfect. You may be better to open a service request about this issue.

Comment: This doesn't answer my actual question. I do not have access to embedding or MS Stream, and in any case talking about other solutions (which aren't even SharePoint) rather misses the point.